# Amazon Web Services - Security - Community AMIs

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

I am experimenting with deep learning using AWS. I have some questions on the security risks of using community AMIs. I noted this post - but [Safety of Amazon Community AMIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525445/safety-of-amazon-community-amis) but more specfically - is the potenital security risk only with regards to data that one puts on the community AMI, or is there is a risk that a malicious person could get access to (data on) your home computer? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AMI is simply an OS and software to install on your AWS instances. There's nothing installed locally. If you put passwords or other personal data on the instances then that might get leaked, and if you downloaded some executable from an instance and ran it locally then that might cause problems, but fundamentally the only system that could be compromised by installing an AMI on an instance is that instance.

If you're feeling paranoid, simply treat the instance as you would any other system not under your exclusive control. [Probably a good idea anyway!]